# Jquery loop over checkbox and check for non checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am wanting to loop over an checkbox input and check if the checkbox ISNT selected then add the value of the checkbox to an array which im wanting to POST through ajax.

I have an example below of looping through checkboxes which are selected but how would i do the inverse of this while still including the `.each`?

```
var categories = [];

$("input[name='categories[]']:checked").each(function () {
  categories.push(this.value);
});
```

Comment: `$("input[name='categories[]']:not(:checked)")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean this?

```
$("input[name='categories[]']").each(function () {
  if (!this.checked) categories.push(this.value);
});
```

or

```js
const categories = $("input[name='categories[]']").not(":checked")  // or ]:not(:checked)")
  .map(function() { return this.value })
  .get();
console.log(categories)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="categories[]" value="1" checked />
<input type="checkbox" name="categories[]" value="2" />
<input type="checkbox" name="categories[]" value="3" checked />
```

Comment: But second solution is more elegant ;)